Flutter slide animation when widget change data
I create a animation on jetpack compose. How can I create it in Flutter?
Jetpack compose code:
@Composable
fun Greeting( modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val isVisible = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

        Button(
            onClick = {
                isVisible.value = !isVisible.value
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Button")
        }

        AnimatedContent(
            targetState = isVisible.value,
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .weight(1f),
            content = {
                if (it) {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Red))
                } else {
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green))
                }
            },
            transitionSpec = {
                slideInHorizontally(
                    initialOffsetX = { if (isVisible.value) -it else it },
                ) togetherWith slideOutHorizontally(
                    targetOffsetX = { if (isVisible.value) it else -it },
                )
            },
            label = "Animation"
        )
    }
}

I tried animated switcher but not worked like I expected.

It is better to share a visual of your desired animation instead of code in another framework. This would help the Flutter developers to address your requirements faster and help you easier.
